# Recursion not Crashing

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, recursion

I have coded this up for a looping picture viewer on my iPad thinking that this will lead to stackoverflow very soon but nothing so far. It's steady (not that i am complaining). But is it a case of opening the champagne before the event or...

```
- (void)showPhotos:(NSMutableArray *)resultSet index:(int)i
{
    i += 1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:PHOTO_DISPLAY_TIME 
                          delay:0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^(void) 
    {
        //get photourl & set it to imageview
        [self.photosImage setAlpha:1.0];
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished) 
    {
        if(finished)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:PHOTO_DISPLAY_TIME 
                                  delay:0 
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                             animations:^(void) 
             {
                 [self.photosImage setAlpha:0.0];
             } 
                             completion:^(BOOL finished) 
             {
                 if(finished)
                     [self showPhotos:resultSet index:i];
             }];
        }
    }];    
    return;
}
```

What I am doing is fading the image in & fading the image out. & then calling the same function again. So this should crash right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this looks like recursive it is not. The completion block will be called asynchronous after the animation finishes. This will be after your method returns.

If you are still unsure about this you can verify that in the debugger. Just place a breakpoint on your second invocation of your method and examine the stack trace every time it fires.

Answer (score 1):

The completion block does not actually get called from within showPhotos. It gets called in the main run loop. showPhotos queues the animation and completes. Later when the animation is done, the completion is queued and the main run loop runs it. The original call to showPhotos has already exited. So you don't have to worry about a stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually just like an infinite loop. You could get the same affect by programming:

```
bool forever = YES;

while (forever) {
    //fade in
    //fade out
}
```

It would cause issues if the method called itself more then once within itself. As this would create exponential multiples of the function trying to run at close to the same time.

```
//this would cause issues
- (void)showPhotos:(NSMutableArray *)resultSet index:(int)i {
    [self showPhotos:resultSet index:i];
    [self showPhotos:resultSet index:i];
}
```

Comment: This is not right, since the animation completion blocks are called asynchronous.